# failed to set breakpoint site at 0x9dd200 for breakpoint 197.1: error sending the breakpoint request

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

I can not make a breakpoint in my xcode.
It print "warning: failed to set breakpoint site at 0x85d5f0 for breakpoint 279.2: error sending the breakpoint request
"  all the time

Comment: I was getting this because I was hitting a `preconditionFailure`

Comment: you founf the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You've most likely deleted the file or the file / folder structure changed such that the breakpoint is now invalid. Switch to the Breakpoint Navigator in Xcode and find (and delete) all the files marked in red. You can even enter "279.2" in the search field below the panel to find out the faulty breakpoint.

If you're unable to create breakpoints still, make sure the file you're adding break point to has been added to the target you're debugging.

Answer (score -2):

In my case I forgot to set initial view controller in storyboard.